# treelike structure plugin for vim

Tags: vim

Does anyone know of some plugin for vim which would enable treelike note keeping organization like in many today's notekeeping applications. For example, something [alike](http://screenshots.en.softonic.com/en/scrn/67000/67366/3_mempad01.jpg) which would according to the tree on the left create another file in a directory structure to enable keeping several files together, under one tree, but still have them all at view.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [VimOutliner](https://github.com/vimoutliner/vimoutliner).

Quote from the website:

> What is VimOutliner?
>
> Vim Outliner is a vim plugin that
>   turns the powerful vim editor into a
>   powerful outliner of the likes of
>   GrandView, More and MaxThink. It is
>   keyboarder friendly and very fast. If
>   you can touchtype, you can outline as
>   fast as you think.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at "DotOutlineTree : Helps you edit structured text".

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1225

"Viki/Deplate : A personal wiki for Vim"

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=861

Comment: DotOutlineTree: Looks interesting, but for some reason I can't make it work (i've read the dot.vim). Do you perchance have an example (simple) file you'd be willing to paste to some of the "paste sites" ?

Comment: I just noticed those plugins time ago when were looking for different ones.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat laborious way of taking notes in a treelike fashion all within vim:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XPC3YQCID8k

Answer (score 1):

You could just use NerdTree, http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658 - the "tree explorer plugin", which alone is useful anyway and work with files from then. Creating directories is as easy as :!mkdir directory.

Answer (score 1):

The [vimwiki](http://code.google.com/p/vimwiki/) plug-in has some nifty features for (nested) lists and checklists. And, of course, many more wiki-related features.

Answer (score 0):

You should try voom plugin http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2657
It is best.